# Play FLV in Android

Tags: android, flash, web, youtube, flv

I want to play FLV videos embedded in a website from youtube. I created a webview and the URL is fetched. When the app is loaded, the video doesn't play. What is the reason? Do i have to perform some extra work?

Comment: from android 4.0 the android doesnt support flash format